# Perceptron Learning Algorithm: what is the probability that the viewed data is linearly separable, after some number of steps?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, perceptron

My understanding is that the Perceptron Learning Algorithm:

- will not converge if the data is not linearly separable.
- might take exponentially many iterations, even if the data is linearly separable.

I'm wondering if, after $k$ steps, anything can be said about the probability that the data is linearly separable?

Comment: Interesting thought, but my hunch is you'll probably have to make some fairly strong assumptions on the distribution of the training data to say anything like this.